# Get value from a <div> element, choose recipient, send it via Ajax (jQuery) to a recipient via email and show confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get a text from a div#main, send the text via Ajax jQuery to a php file from where I wil send it via email.

The user can choose the recipient of the from a multiple radio buttons choices on the site.

After I send the data to the PHP file I want to do some styles (e.g. remove a class, etc..).

So far I have this, can you tell me if it is right?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'email.php',
            email: { recipient: $('input[type=radio]:checked').attr("value")},
            data: { content: $('#main').text()},
            success: function()
            {
                $("#email").removeClass("active");
            }

        });
    });

});
```

PS: I dont have the PHP file yet, I want just to figure out if my Ajax solution above is the right way to do what I've described.

Answer (score 0):

All of the data that you want to send back to the server needs to be in the data property. Also, you probably want to use the `val()` method rather than accessing the value attribute directly.

```
data: { content: $('#main').text(), recipient: $('input:radio:checked').val() },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.post("email.php", { recipient: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val(), content: $('#main').text()}, function(){
              $("#email").removeClass("active");
        });    
    });
});
```